# How to setup client certificates article outdated

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Building Secure ASP.NET Applications: Authentication, Authorization, and Secure Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649247.aspx)

There is a note a the top of this article that says the content is outdated. What is the newer way of doing it then? Or am I misunderstanding?

> **Retired Content**
>
> This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. It is
>   provided as a courtesy for individuals who are still using these
>   technologies. This page may contain URLs that were valid when
>   originally published, but now link to sites or pages that no longer
>   exist.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking if that page is obsolete? Well, it was last updated 10 years ago and applies to ASP.NET 1.1 and 2.0 (5 is the latest IIRC) and Windows Server 2003 which EOLed earlier this year, so yeah. Are you asking how to create an IIS site which accepts client certificates?

Comment: The note sounds like there is something more secure than using client certificates or newer. I may have  misunderstood once again.